# Code First ASP.NET MVC App, Seed method isn't getting called

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-setup-mvc5-website-mysql-entity-framework-6-code-first-vs2013/) to get a working ASP.NET MVC application up using a MySQL database. I got all the way through it but discovered that, when starting my application the Seed method I overrode never gets called.

```
public class MyDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyDbContext context)
    {
        //Roles
        context.Roles.Add(new Role { role = "admin" });
        context.Roles.Add(new Role { role = "user" });

        //Users
        context.Users.Add(new User { userName = "test", firstName = "Elliot", lastName = "Alderson", email = "ealderson@allsafe.com", phone = "555-555-5555", city = "New York", state = "New York", zipCode = "10001" });

        //User Roles
        context.UserRoles.Add(new UserRole { userName = "test", role = "admin" });

        //Logins
        context.Logins.Add(new Login { userName = "test", password = "test" });

        //Credit Cards
        context.CreditCards.Add(new CreditCard { userName = "test", creditCardNumber = "1234432156788765", expirationDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1), svn = "123", brand = "Evil Corp" });

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Googling around, I discovered I needed to add the context in my app's web.config file nested in the entityFramework tag which I did

```
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
  <contexts>
    <context type="COS492_SIP.DAL.MyDbContext, COS492_SIP">
      <databaseInitializer type="COS492_SIP.DAL.MyDbInitializer, COS492_SIP" />
    </context>
  </contexts>
</entityFramework>
```

And finally, I changed my global.asax file to force initializing the database context which also did not work

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbInitializer());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

I think this has something to do with the backend database being MySQL (I can't switch to a different one) since the entityFramework tags reference mssql. If thats the case how do I fix this and, either way, how do I call the seed method?

**Edit**

MyDbContext Class

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{

    public MyDbContext() : base("MyDbContextConnectionString")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbInitializer());
    }

    public DbSet<CreditCard> CreditCards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Login> Logins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Web Config connection string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDbContextConnectionString" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;UserId=root;Password=toor;database=gilbert_sip;CharSet=utf8;Persist Security Info=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you have to do `update-database` in Package Manager Console for `Seed()` to be called.

Comment: Throws this error No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'COS492_SIP'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration).

Comment: Are you sure you have a `<connectionStrings>` entry in web.config which points to the database? I don't know how to set one up for MySQL, but I know it goes in the `<configuration>` section. At least with SQL Server, it is necessary in addition to the `defaultConnectionFactory`.

Comment: Can you show your MyDbContext class definition ? I think you need to move your code line: System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbInitializer()); to MyDbContext constructor

Comment: @KentWeigel H-Herzl just added connectionStrings and MyDbContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your `Application_Start`:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(new MyDbInitializer());
var db = new MyDbContext();
db.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Comment: Seems like that got me closer. Web app threw an error Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Comment: Got it working, Had to install the NuGet packages. Thanks!